# Float right & left don't work properly

Tags: html, css

On my new site www.unicmedia.nl/case/oranje i have a problem with my floats. In IE they work (for the first time lol) but FF and CH are way off.

I tried literally everything but can't seem to find the problem. My css code is valid according to the w3c validator.

Hope you guys can find something that is wrong!

Screen: [Incorrect](http://www.plaatjesupload.nl/bekijken/3946946.html) [Correct](http://www.plaatjesupload.nl/bekijken/3946952.html)

Comment: You might want to explain what the expected behavior is and what is actually happening. At least a screenshot.

Comment: In addition to validating your CSS, please validate your HTML markup. Next, please be more specific when you tell us what you expect to happen, and what is really happening. Finally, you may get better results if you post the relevant parts of your code into jsfiddle.net so we can actively edit and test it.

Comment: It looks fine to me. What do you want?

Comment: Okay, I will do that, one sec

Comment: Code added http://jsfiddle.net/PVsHm/

Comment: In Safari, screen "Correct" looks just the same as screen "Incorrect".

Comment: Floats work great when you set their width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div with id=content=right should have some width. Please set it to 600px.

Note that a parent element should float if one of its child elements floats. Thats is why the div#content appears outside its children. To make the parent element not float you can use the clearfix hack.

http://www.positioniseverything.net/easyclearing.html

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that page, I see a `div` with the class `content-left`. It looks floated left, but it's also got 25px of margin-left. Is that what you mean by "way off"?

Your content-right div is also floated left. Are you trying to make two columns? The problem might be that your right content has so much information that it's trying to be full-width so not floating. If you force it to be a specific number of pixels or percent, that should make that work. Try making your content-left `width: 20%` and your content-right `width:80%`.

Better yet, start with [someone else's cross-browser column layout](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/).

Comment: 20 percent and 80 percent did not work out for me.. Thanks for your help!